Как в ассемблерном коде использовать переменную, взятую из файла с++?
Есть проект на с++ в visual studio. Я создал файл source.asm, который должен будет вывести переменную, взятую из файла с++ (main.cpp). Это MASM x86. Напишите код на ассемблере masm x86, который будет выводить на экран переменную, взятую из файла с++. Также напишите код заголовочного файла main.h. код main.cpp выглядит так:
extern "C" int source()
int main() { float x = 1.2; cout << source(); }

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55906722/4711135
